# pinescript get index of pivothigh

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v4

I would like to get the bar index of the last occurrence of pivothigh so I can use it to plot an indicator starting from that index. Not familiar with pinescript and the references are limited

Answer (score 2):

You can usesr the built-in `barssince` function and use the result in the history reference operator `[]`

```
barssincePhigh = barssince(phigh)
barssincePlow = barssince(plow)
```

However your pivots trigger after 10 bars by default, add `leftbars` value to the barsisnce result to show the high/low pivot:

```
//@version=4
study("Pivot Prices", overlay=true)

leftbars = input(10, minval=1, title='Bars to the left')
rightbars = input(10, minval=1, title='Bars to the right')

phigh = pivothigh(high, leftbars, rightbars)
plow = pivotlow(low, leftbars, rightbars)

barssincePhigh = barssince(phigh) + leftbars
barssincePlow = barssince(plow) + leftbars

if phigh
    label1 = label.new(bar_index[barssincePhigh], high[barssincePhigh], text=tostring(high[barssincePhigh]), style = label.style_labeldown, color = color.orange)

if plow
    label2 = label.new(bar_index[barssincePlow], low[barssincePlow], text=tostring(low[barssincePlow]), style = label.style_labelup, color = color.green)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer is wrong.
ta.pivothigh
This function returns the price of the pivot high point. It returns 'NaN', if there was no pivot high point.

[see the image to understand]
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnnKL.png